# How to "hot" deploy war dependency in Jboss using Jboss Tools Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-tools

I'm using Jboss tools (3.0.0 alpha, on Eclipse 3.4) to hot deploy my war on Jboss 4.2.3.
My war depends on another project (packed inside a jar) I 'm working on.
But, when I save a file in this project(the jar project), Jboss Tools republish the compiled classes of the war project, but does not re deploy the classes changed in the jar project.(actually the war project is deployed "exploded" in the deploy directory, but the jar project is deployed, as a jar, in the WEB-INF/libs directory)
I would like eclipse and JBoss tools to republish the classes from the jar project, like they do for the JSPs and classes inside the war project...
Thank you for your help !
Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that to happen you need your jar to be a dependent utility jar so when the packaging via web tools happens it will package the jar changes too.

If that is not enough flexibility for you then consider using the Project Archives functionality of JBoss Tools which allows you to define the dependencies as you want it.

p.s. using solutions like JavaRebel does not help if the problem is about getting the proper files copied.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaRebel. They use Java Instrumentation API (javaagent) to reload classes when they change on the file system.

Comment: JavaRebel is a commercial solution, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, JavaRebel is commercial. If it's the proper tool for the problem and within budget, he should try it. I don't use it, because restarting Tomcat is fast enough for me :)